# TikZ cycle through foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

Dears,

I am facing the following problem. Given a set of points, I have to draw the geometric shape of these points, however, I have to do this programmatically. Take a look at this MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                % nodes
                \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
                \coordinate (b) at (1, 0);
                \coordinate (c) at (1, 1);
                \coordinate (d) at (0, 1);

                % block
                \def\blockA{a, b, c, d}

                % draw cycle
                % - static way
                \draw[fill=gray!50, draw = white] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;

                % - desired way
                \foreach \v [count=\i] in \blockA {
                    % ...
                }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I need to find proper ways to implement the `% - desired way`. I would like to know if anyone has ever worked with this. If anyone has any questions or suggestions, please feel free to let me know.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here you don't need the `\blockA` macro, since you can just write `\foreach \v [count=\i] in {a, b, c, d}` then use `\v` inside parentheses to create node names. But it needs a bit more of work to draw the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is

```
\draw [fill=red] (a)
\foreach \v [count=\i] in \blockA {
    \ifnum\i>1
        -- (\v)
    \fi
}
-- cycle;
```

which yields:

[image]

since the `red` fill was done on top of the `gray!50`.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                % nodes
                \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
                \coordinate (b) at (1, 0);
                \coordinate (c) at (1, 1);
                \coordinate (d) at (0, 1);

                % block
                \def\blockA{a, b, c, d}

                % draw cycle
                % - static way
                \draw[fill=gray!50, draw = white] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;

                % - desired way
                \draw [fill=red] (a)
                \foreach \v [count=\i] in \blockA {
                    \ifnum\i>1
                        -- (\v)
                    \fi
                }
                -- cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very thank you! That is exactly what I am looking for.